# Images won't scale with boot strap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, scale

I have images placed in my website using the < img> tag. When the website is scaled to a smaller screen the images hang over the container. Why are they not scaling with the the rest of the site? Any fixes?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4 padtop">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/WDadd.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is the right way to do it, but it seems to be working for me you could try to add, give it the class thumbnail on the image, and if you dont like the look of thumbnail you can always edit it in your css file

example: http://jsfiddle.net/abnH6/6/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4 padtop">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="" class="thumbnail"/></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, good call. I did this and it fixes the issue. I just remove the border in the CSS. Well played good sir! thank you!